# Disable automatic PivotTable refresh on Data Model change?

Tags: excel

I have a data model in Power Pivot, and numerous PivotTables in Excel which connect to it. Every time I make a change to the data model, I have to wait for all the PivotTables to refresh. Some of them I want to refresh, but most I don’t. How can I turn off this automatic refresh for certain pivot tables whenever the data model changes? I understand that there used to be an option to do so by simply right-clicking on each pivot table, but that seems to have been discontinued. Is there a way to do this, perhaps with VBA?